# How may I be redirected to another app when i click a link on my app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, xml, hyperlink

I'm working on an app and in that I have added some activities which opens an WebView html file. And in that html file I have added iframe of google docs and I have added some url of another app in that Docs file. And if I click the url it's opening it in the same page and "web page not available" is coming. Those links should be redirected to another app, Please say a solution for it. And sorry if it was a silly question because I'm a way too fresher for android studio and codings.

Answer (score 0):

you should read about `Deep Linking` for starters
here's the google documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

for your own problem you will need to search for the `Deep Linking URL` for the App you want to redirect to and then put that URL instead of what you are using now, if the App you want to redirect to is also created by you and has not implemented Deep Linking then this is a feature that you MUST implement, i would suggest reading up about Dynamic Linking for easier implementation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links